# KeyboardAvoidingView not working properly in React Native: Form doesn't move up with the keyboard

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm facing an issue with KeyboardAvoidingView in my React Native app. I expect the form to move up when the keyboard is opened so that it doesn't overlap the user input. However, only the "No Account?" button moves up, while the form itself remains in place.

I have used KeyboardAvoidingView and set the behavior prop to "padding" for iOS and "height" for other platforms. I also tried wrapping the component in a ScrollView, but it didn't solve the problem.

Why is KeyboardAvoidingView not working, and how can I fix this issue? I would appreciate any help and suggestions. Thank you!

Additional Details:

- React Native Version: 0.71.8
- Packages Used: expo - 48.0.18
- Tested Devices/Simulators: iPhone 14 Pro Max - iOS 16.4

Here's my code:

````
import { View, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, Text, Platform, Image, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, KeyboardAvoidingView, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard } from "react-native";
// some imports

const LoginScreen = ({ route }) => {
  // some useStates

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
    >
      <SafeAreaView style={[styles.wrapper, { backgroundColor: bgValue }]}>
        <View style={GlobalStyles.container}>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "stretch", justifyContent: "space-between", height: "100%" }}>
              <View>
                <Text style={[GlobalStyles.text, { marginBottom: 5 }]}>Email</Text>
                <TextInput style={[GlobalStyles.textInput, { marginBottom: 15 }]} value={email} onChangeText={(text) => {setEmail(text);}}/>
                <Text style={[GlobalStyles.text, { marginBottom: 5 }]}>Пароль</Text>
                <View style={{ position: "relative" }}>
                  <TextInput style={[GlobalStyles.textInput, { marginBottom: 0 }]} secureTextEntry={passwordHidden} value={password} onChangeText={(text) => { setPassword(text); }}/>
                  <View style={{ position: "absolute", right: 15, flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "center", height: "100%" }}>
                    {passwordHidden ? (
                      <Ionicons name="eye" size={24} onPress={() => { setPasswordHidden(false); }}/>
                    ) : (
                      <Ionicons name="eye-off" size={24} onPress={() => { setPasswordHidden(true); }}/>
                    )}
                  </View>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={[GlobalStyles.darkBtn, { marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 10 }]}
                  activeOpacity={0.7}
                >
                  <Text style={[GlobalStyles.text, { color: "#fff", fontFamily: "Rubik-Bold" }]}>Войти</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.7}
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate("Register");
              }}
            >
              <Text style={[GlobalStyles.text, { textAlign: "center", textDecorationLine: "underline" }]}>No account?</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
     flex: 1,
  },
});```
````

Comment: where is the "No Account" button in your code

Answer (score 0):

Azamat!
I checked your code and i recommending you change the tags position, first put SafeAreaView and inside KeyboardAvoidingView

> 

maybe this is the problem, too can modify the "enable" prop of KeyboardAvoidView tag, try change to **enabled={false}**.
In case the problem no resolve, maybe can check your AndroidManifest and verify in Activity tag if exist the next prop

> <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
> android:label="@string/app_name" {...}
> **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"** >{...}

in android this can necesary, i dont know if this prop is necesary in IOS. Luck!

Comment: Did not work :(